# Unique data based on name,email from sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get unique rows based on FirstName,EmailID. I tried few things by adding DISTINCT to all row that still get duplicate rows. tried Group By that failed with error. I can do a subquery but that will be slow. WHat is the best solution for below query

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,FamilyName, EmailID,Phone,City,Country,CreatedOn,t.Type , ID
FROM Forms C JOIN Form_Type T 
ON c.Form_TypeID = t.Form_TypeID 
WHERE c.Form_TypeID = 1 AND  DATEDIFF( "d", CreatedOn, GETDATE()) < 31
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,FamilyName, EmailID,Phone,City,Country,CreatedOn,t.Type , ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName ,EmailID ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC ) NewCol
    FROM Forms C
    JOIN Form_Type T ON c.Form_TypeID = t.Form_TypeID
    WHERE c.Form_TypeID = 1
        AND DATEDIFF("d", CreatedOn, GETDATE()) < 31
    ) t
WHERE NewCol = 1
```

I have added an extra column (i.e. NewCol) in the inner table. I am assuming that you wanted to display recent record (using CREATEDON) for each combination of "FirstName, Email"

Comment: It doesn't fetch any record

Comment: Can you just execute the inner query and see if you are getting results? and give a sample of output? (only worried about firstname, email id, NewCol values)

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` will not work in your case, as you want *all* the fields from the table. So you need to use a sub-query to create a list of distinct names/emails.

You should be able to adapt the following example to your needs:

```
SELECT User, EMail, Address1, Address2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(User, EMail) FROM Table1) tmp ON t1.User = tmp.User AND t1.EMail = tmp.EMail
```

Using an `INNER JOIN` this returns only rows from `Table1` that are in table `tmp`. Table `tmp` is defined as the distinct combinations of `User` and `EMail` from `Table1`.

So what happens is: You create a distinct list of `User` and `EMail` from `Table1`. Then you select all the entries from `Table1` where `User` and `EMail` are in that list.

Comment: It still gets duplicate data.

Comment: May be CTE is the solution

Comment: @Learning Are you sure that you don't have multiple records with the same first name and email? In that case: How should uniqueness be defined? Which of the records should be returned?

Comment: I am sure i have multiple records with same details other than different ID in database as ID is Auto Incremental fields. Some duplicate are result of submitting same form multiple types.

Comment: In that case, if the duplicate records really contain the same data except for the ID, a `SELECT DISTINCT FieldName1, FieldName2, ... FROM TableX` should work, really. If there are records where first name and email are equal, but other data is different, then my code is correct in returning multiple records, as then first name and email are simply not sufficient to identify a record uniquely.